# WPF List box sorting not working

Tags: wpf, sorting, listbox

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here - just starting out learning WPF - the code sorts for the initial binding but then does not work after that?

```
private void SortSeriesList(string sortDirection) {

    ListBoxSeries.Items.SortDescriptions.Clear();

    switch (sortDirection) {
        case "asc":
            ListBoxSeries.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription("SeriesName", System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending));
            break;
        case "desc":
            ListBoxSeries.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription("SeriesName", System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Descending));
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: How do you call the SortSeriesList method?